# Routers can not obtain DHCP lease from modem, but PC can

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, modem, isp

I have two different routers from different brands, neither of which can obtain a DHCP lease from the modem. But if I connect a PC directly to the modem, it obtains one connects immediately. This only started happening today, after years of regular use without issue. What could be the problem?

I've verified that the modem is connected to the routers on the WAN port rather than one of the four LAN ports. I have also tried rebooting the modem and/or router in every order and combination. I've also reset both of the routers to factory settings. None of these troubleshooting steps seem make any difference in behavior.

Comment: there's thousands of brands/models of "routers" - can you add details of the routers. You say the routers (both?) used to work until today? what changed

Comment: If the modem is doing DHCP then try connecting the modem to the routers' LAN ports not WAN.  The routers should  be acting as switches not routers.

Comment: @blindspots you might be onto something - Maybe the modem and router both are trying to use the same IP address range.

Comment: @davidgo - but *started happening today, after years of regular use without issue* - why would OP need to change anything if nothing changed?

Comment: @JaromandaX  Doh. I can't read.

Comment: @davidgo - happens :p

Comment: Some routers (or switches or modems...) can be configured to accept only a limited number (including just 1) of MAC addresses on a port and will ignore any other. So does a router work better if before connecting it to the modem, you power cycle the modem first and make sure the PC is not connected anywhere around? modem's firmware could have been updated by ISP?

Comment: @JaromandaX *"years of regular use"* but not necessarily "no changes."  OP had an original problem (?) then started swapping router`s` and connections and troubleshooting.  We don't know what's been changed and/or reset.  We don't know the actual hardware involved or how it was originally connected at any given point.

Comment: I ended up factory resetting the modem, which made the problem go away, at least for now. I suspect a misconfiguration in the modem pushed by the ISP or some other kind of corruption, but can't verify as I can not access any modem diagnostics info.

Comment: @JaromandaX Modem is ES2251, routers are ASUS RT-AC1750 B1 and TP-Link Archer C7

Comment: @BlindSpots Plugging modem into LAN worked, but I'd prefer to have the router take the IP and perform NAT.

Comment: @davidgo modem assigns a public IP, not a private IP.

Comment: @A.B I've reset both modem and router in every order and combination to no effect.

Comment: I still don't understand what kind of error could cause a brownout that a PC can handle, but a router can't. It's very weird. Is there anything in the DHCP protocol that routers don't support but PCs do?

Comment: *"Plugging modem into LAN worked"* that is instructive.  This strikes me as a config issue.  You have two routers exhibiting the same behavior but work fine as switches.  Edit your question to include the make and model numbers of the routers and we can provide more specific info.  Also the PC's IP address.  **Note:** if you use the router behind modem (DHCP), it must serve private addresses in a subnet that is different than the modem.